# How to change text to all in v-table vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table, vuetify-datatable

Currently I can change the number of options but what I don't know is how to change all to `Todos`, What can I do to change it ?

[image: image example]

```
<v-data-table
     :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
 ...>
```

Edit:

[image: image example 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more property in `:footer-props` attribute value object.

```
'items-per-page-all-text':'Todos'
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.7/dist/vuetify.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.7/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[15, 30, 50, 100, -1], 'items-per-page-all-text':'Todos'}"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you also know how to change search to "buscar" of the header and the no data available of the table to "no información disponible"? , in the original question I add a reference image

Comment: update: I already made the search change in the label of my v-text-field, but I still can't change the "no available data" to "no información disponible"

Comment: update:  I already made change in v-data-table with the property no-data-text="no información disponible", also If you know where are documentation about properties let me know I wanna learn more

Comment: @plasticheart For all the configuration and settings. You can have a look this official documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/